# How to add data like this in Firebase's Cloud Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

In JavaScript, I wrote something like this but it returns error > "Document references must have an even number of segments". I need to use "set" and not "add" for my case.

```
const ref= db.collection("product");
ref.doc("111").doc("category").set({ clothes: true });
```

In Firebase's Realtime Database, I can write the code like this but in Firestore I can't.

```
ref.child("111").child("category").set({ clothes: true });
```

How to write the code like this in Firestore?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here seems to be that you are trying to use doc in a doc. This is not the design of the Firestore. The collection can have documents and documents can have collections like this example.

```
var messageRef = db.collection('product').doc('productNumbers')
            .collection('11111').doc('category');
```

You have to change a little bit your data structure to correspond to the design. Here is a [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model)